# Restrict text box to start with a particular character

Tags: javascript, html

In Html, I need to restrict users from entering text box that should start with a particular character/number,

(example: number 6- In this case the user can enter numbers in the text box that are starting only with "6")

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? On SO, you are encouraged to try to solve the problem yourself first, before the community offers assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following?

```
<input onblur="if (!/^6/.test(this.value)) alert('Ooops');">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a piece of javascript to check this client side. Don't forget to also validate the input server side! Everyone doesn't have javascript enabled and malicious users could just disable it to circumvent your checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textbox").on("keypress",function(e){

//you can use e.which or e.keyCode based on the browser
//check if it is the first character
//here i used 56 as it is keycode for your example of 6
if($("#textbox").val().length ==0 && e.which == 56)
{

   alert("yes i accept");

}
else
{

   alert("no i dont accept");

}

});
```